# Change trace parameters for schema change history report

Tags: sql-server, schema, ssms

How do you change trace parameters for schema change history report? I ran a report and it only gave me details for the last 5 days.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? This is a product specific question.

Comment: Hi Sorry - I was out of network coverage for a while. I am using SQL Management Studio 2012.